# ColdFusion ORM not deleting or cascading

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, hibernate-mapping

When I am updating a CF ORM object, if one of the children is no longer there, it only sets the linked value to null then does not delete the item or any of its children. Below is the definition of my parent object and subsequent child. (The children hanging off of it are defined as well)

Bulletin:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" accessors="true" table="bulletins">
    <cfproperty name="id" column="ID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" ormtype="int" unsavedvalue="0">
    <cfproperty name="affectedModels" fieldtype="one-to-many" cfc="affectedModel" fkColumn="bulletinId" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
</cfcomponent>
```

AffectedModel:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" accessors="true" table="affectedModels">
    <cfproperty name="id" column="ID" fieldtype="id" generator="identity" ormtype="int" unsavedvalue="0">
    <cfproperty name="bulletin" fieldType="many-to-one" cfc="bulletin" column="bulletinId" notNull="true" >
    <cfproperty name="affectedYears" fieldtype="collection" type="array" fkcolumn="affectedModelId" table="affectedYears" elementColumn="prodYear" elementType="string" lazy="false" cascade="all">
</cfcomponent>
```

This all works well enough to add and update, however if I remove an "affectedModel" all CF ORM does is null the bulletinId field.  It does not remove the row, or the subsequent row in the affectedYears table.

Any suggestions as to why this would be happening or what I could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `inverse="true"` to the `affectedModels` property of the **Bulletins** entity.

I covered the same problem [in a blog post a while back](http://fusiongrokker.com/post/on-cascaded-hibernate-deletes). The solution actually ended up being submitted in the comments (I had inverse on the wrong side of the relationship).

Also, you say:

> if I remove an "affectedModel"

Does this mean you're doing `bulletin.removeAffectedModel( affectedModel );`, or are you deleting the model with `entityDelete( affectedModel )`? If the former, it would not delete the data, only the relationship between them, which would explain the result you're seeing. In order to delete data, you need to run `entityDelete()`.

Comment: When I speak of removing an "affectedModel" I am referring to persisting the bulletin object with one less "affectedModel" in the array of affected models.  This results in the nulling of the bulletinID field in the affectedModels table but not the removal of the row or its subsequent array of affected years in the affectedYears table.  I have the same result if I remove the affected years from the affectedModel.  Also, I attempted to use the inverse="true", same result, just a null bulletinId, nothing removed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to `entityDelete()` the affectedModel that you want removed, then.

Comment: Would entityDelete() of the bulletin object be sufficient or do I need to delve in to the bulletin object and iterate over the list of affectedModels calling entityDelete() on each of them and then finally on the bulletin?

Comment: If you have `inverse` and cascading setup properly, then deleting the bulletin should delete the affectedModels, too.

Comment: It appears to only be nulling the bulletin ID and not deleting the orphans.

Comment: Have you added `inverse=true` to the `affectedModels` property of the `bulletin` entity?